# Where is Yarn storing offline packages?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install all the dependencies for this repo:
https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation

The problem is that Yarn seems to have stored offline packages somewhere other than the cache directory and it quickly ran out of space in my system drive. I cleaned the cache (`yarn cache clean`) and deleted the modules folder (`node_modules/`), then ran `yarn` and sure enough it installed about 4GB of dependencies in less than 5 mins (with an internet connection of 2 MBits)

As a side note, I'd like to know if there is a way to disable the cache in both `yarn` and `npm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2049 says they are stored at this positions:

> ```
> %LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/config/global on Windows  
> ~/.config/yarn/global on OSX and non-root Linux
> /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global on Linux if logged in as root
> ```

And I think disabling cache is currently an open topic for yarn: https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/pull/53

Comment: Linux:  /usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v4/

Comment: This has probably changed on Mac OS X since the answer was given. Since this is version dependent, might as well stick to @safety's answer, using `yarn cache dir`.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be correct for me on Linux. See @safety's answer instead.

Comment: The current logic for the cache directory in Yarnv1 is here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/3119382885ea373d3c13d6a846de743eca8c914b/src/util/user-dirs.js#L26

Comment: A notable gotcha in the above logic is that for root, `userHome` is not `$HOME` (typically `/root`) but `/usr/local/share`.

Answer (score 48):

You can run `yarn cache dir` to list the cache location on your system.

Comment: if, like me, you've changed the cache dir (`yarn config set cache-folder ~/Desktop/folder`) and are trying to set it back (on mac os) ..the default seems to be `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Yarn/`

Comment: PS D:\> yarn cache dir
Unknown Syntax Error: Command not found; did you mean one of:

  0. yarn cache clean [--mirror] [--all]
  1. yarn cache clean [--mirror] [--all]

While running cache dir. Using yarn 3.3.1.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, all node versions with default yarn versions and cache locations:-

```
❯ for i in boron carbon dubnium erbium fermium; \
       docker run -it node:$i bash -c "yarn --version && yarn cache dir"
1.15.2
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v4
1.21.1
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
1.22.4
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
1.22.4
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
1.22.5
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
```

Comment: I use nvm and this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

An updated and expanded version of the great answer by Gavin Gilmour:

#### As Root

```
boron
1.15.2
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v4
carbon
1.21.1
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
dubnium
1.22.5
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
erbium
1.22.17
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
fermium
1.22.15
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
gallium
1.22.15
/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6
```

#### As User

When using `--user node` at the CLI or `USER node` in a Dockerfile for a rootless container:

```
boron
1.15.2
/home/node/.cache/yarn/v4
carbon
1.21.1
/home/node/.cache/yarn/v6
dubnium
1.22.5
/home/node/.cache/yarn/v6
erbium
1.22.17
/home/node/.cache/yarn/v6
fermium
1.22.15
/home/node/.cache/yarn/v6
gallium
1.22.15
/home/node/.cache/yarn/v6
```

Not sure why yarn regressed in the latter two, but I verified it with other tags for those releases as well.

Comment: what's with the `v4` and `v6`? any specific reason?

Comment: I use nvm and this is not true.